# Transform a website address from Plan English to a Valid URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am developing a ChatBot using Dialogflow. At a step, I ask for the website from the user.

Often time the user provides the website address is:

`It is www dot google dot com`,

`google dot com`

I am using [sys.url](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) entity from Dialogflow. It is working fine to detect the URL from user input but it does not transform it into well-formatted URL like `www.google.com` from `www dot google dot com`.

My goal is to transform the above website address from plain English to a valid URL. Is it possible?

One solution is that I remove spaces and replace "dot" with "." but that will not work with domains that have "dot" in the names.

Is there any node.js or Javascript library that we can use to solve this? Any way to use some Regex? So ultimately I want:

`www dot google dot com` -> `www.google.com`

`google dot com` -> `google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions in combination with the `replace` function:

```js
var str = "www dot google dot com";

var res = str.replace(/dot/g, ".");

res = res.replace(/\s/g,"");

alert(res);
```

Comment: What will happen to www dot dot solutions dot com?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal test it out for yourself

Comment: This is not working. It is transforming "www dot reddotsolutions dot com" into www.red.solutions.com